# In a table of tasks, how can I save that a user has marked a task as complete/incomplete using checkboxes in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my view, a foreach loop iterates through my Model list and displays all tasks the user has as a table. This is a snippet of how it looks

```
<form method="post" asp-action="EditComplete" asp-controller="ToDoTask">
    <table>
        @foreach (ToDoTask todo in Model)
        {
            <tr class="theTasks" data-row="row @todo.Id">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="roundCheckbox" data-row="row @todo.Id" name="IsCompleted" value="true" onchange="this.form.submit()" @(todo.IsCompleted ? "checked" : "")/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@todo.Id"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</form>
```

The post method takes in a ToDoTask object as a parameter with the Bind attribute like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditComplete([Bind("Id,IsCompleted")]ToDoTask task)
{
  int taskId = task.Id;
  bool isCompleted = task.IsCompleted;
  ToDoTask theTask = _repo.GetTodoById(taskId);

   if(theTask == null)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }

     theTask.IsCompleted = isCompleted;
    _repo.UpdateTask(theTask);
     await _repo.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The issue is it only seems to be saving one task's information (the Id), because when I try to save multiple tasks, the id for all of them are the same and it just updates that one tasks with the reused Id. Does the app only remember one Id? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So my advice:**

You can use **AJAX** to send the request.

- You can learn AJAX [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) for free if you are interested.

Add the id value in the `value` property in the `input` tag.
Remove any unnecessary code if you have any.

```
@foreach(ToDoTask todo in Model){
<tr class="theTasks" data-row="row @todo.Id">
 <td>  
   <input type="checkbox" class="itemId roundCheckbox" data-row="row @todo.Id" name="IsCompleted" value="todo.Id" @(todo.IsCompleted ? "checked" : "")/>
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@todo.Id"/>
 </td>                                    
</tr>
}
```

after that, use JQUERY and AJAX to send the request to your controller.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".itemId").on('change',function (){
            var itemId = $(this).val();

            var d = {id: itemId};

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("EditComplete", "ToDoTask")', 
                //I believe these URL is correct for you, if not change it.
                data: d,
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.success == "Success"){
                        //When it is success reload the page.
                        //This won't work unless you change the controller.
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("something went wrong");
                        //Worst error handling. Check best practices.
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code above will update the task status on every time the checkbox is changed.

For the **location.Reload()** function to work you should change the return value in your controller.
**return a new JSON** in the controller method you have specified.
`return Json(new { success = "Success" });` and you are all set.

You can modify this code to your liking and coding style.